# Change text color in delphi (Console application)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I know the question I've asked seems similar to others however it doesn't seem to apply.

I am using `delphi 10.3`

I want to write two texts consecutively in the console application however I want them separate colors

```
writeln('yes just give me a minute, i need to talk to the manager'); {i want this in the default color}
writeln('Oi Dave we got another thick one shall i just pass him through as self employed'); {i want this to be in red}
writeln('Dont worry u dont have to complete this one') {and this one back to the default color}
```

Comment: I think you need [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute)

Comment: im sorry can u explain how

Comment: Here is a helper library for console apps: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SetConsoleTextAttribute` as already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980596/change-text-color-in-delphi-console-application#comment102370590_57980596) to the question. Example:

```delphi
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, winapi.windows;

var
  ConOut: THandle;
  BufInfo: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
begin
    writeln('yes just give me a minute, i need to talk to the manager');

    // get console screen buffer handle
    ConOut := TTextRec(Output).Handle;  // or GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

    // save current text attributes
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ConOut, BufInfo);

    // set foreground color to red
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(TTextRec(Output).Handle, FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_RED);

    writeln('Oi Dave we got another thick one shall i just pass him through as self employed');

    // reset to defaults
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(ConOut, BufInfo.wAttributes);

    writeln('Dont worry u dont have to complete this one');
    readln;
end.
```

Minimum required reading: [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) and [character attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#_win32_character_attributes).

Don't forget to add error handling.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a treat what would i have to change it to get other colours

Answer (score 4):

I use too the `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function defined in `WinAPI.Windows`.

With this simple procedure (extensible):

```
/// <summary> Cambiar el color de la salida de consola </summary>
/// <summary> Change the color of console output</summary>
procedure SetColorConsole(AColor:TColor);
begin
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_BLUE);
  case AColor of
    clWhite:  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    clRed:    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    clGreen:  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    clBlue:   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_BLUE or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    clMaroon: SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    clPurple: SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_BLUE or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    clAqua: SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_BLUE or FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  end;
end;
```

You can use something like this:

```
  WriteLn(' ');
  SetColorConsole(clWhite);
  WriteLn('clWhite');
  SetColorConsole(clRed);
  WriteLn('clRed');
  SetColorConsole(clGreen);
  WriteLn('clGreen');
  SetColorConsole(clBlue);
  WriteLn('clBlue');
  SetColorConsole(clMaroon);
  WriteLn('clYellow');
  SetColorConsole(clPurple);
  WriteLn('clPurple');
  SetColorConsole(clAqua);
  WriteLn('clAqua');
```

And the result is like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an very easy solution for that, using [DelphiConsole](https://github.com/JensBorrisholt/DelphiConsole)

```
var
  CurrentColor : TConsoleColor;

CurrentColor :=  Console.ForegroundColor;
Console.WriteLine('yes just give me a minute, i need to talk to the manager'); 

Console.ForegroundColor := TConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine('Oi Dave we got another thick one shall i just pass him through as self employed');

Console.ForegroundColor := DefaultColor;
Console.WriteLine('Dont worry u dont have to complete this one');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
Writeln('Standard write without special color');
ColoredWrite('This {color:yellow}Text {color:red}is {color:blue}very {color:black_on_blue} colorful{color:reset} but ends without color');
Writeln('');
ColoredWrite('{color:red}Red{color:red2}Red2{color:green}Green{color:green2}Green2{color:blue}Blue{color:blue2}Blue2'
           + '{color:yellow}Yellow{color:yellow2}Yellow2{color:purple}Purple{color:purple2}Purple2'
           + '{color:gray}Gray{color:black_on_blue}Black on Blue{color:white} White {color:red_on_white}Red on White'
           + '{color:reset} Original Color');
Writeln('');
Writeln('Standard write without special color');
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

And here is the necessary function:

```
uses Winapi.Windows, System.Generics.Collections;

procedure ColoredWrite(sString: string);
var
  ConOut: THandle;
  BufInfo: TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
  ColorDict: TDictionary<string, integer>;
  iPos, iFirstPos: integer;
  sFirstFind: string;
  sKey: string;
begin
  ColorDict := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create();
  ColorDict.Add('{color:red}', FOREGROUND_RED);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:red2}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_RED);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:green}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_GREEN);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:green2}', FOREGROUND_GREEN);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:blue}', FOREGROUND_BLUE);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:blue2}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_BLUE);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:yellow}', FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_GREEN);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:yellow2}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_GREEN);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:purple}', FOREGROUND_BLUE or FOREGROUND_RED);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:purple2}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_BLUE or FOREGROUND_RED);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:gray}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:white}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_RED or FOREGROUND_GREEN or FOREGROUND_BLUE);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:black_on_blue}', 0 or {BACKGROUND_RED or} BACKGROUND_BLUE or BACKGROUND_GREEN);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:red_on_white}', FOREGROUND_INTENSITY or FOREGROUND_RED or 0 or BACKGROUND_INTENSITY or BACKGROUND_RED or BACKGROUND_BLUE or BACKGROUND_GREEN);
  //Write(' '); // If there is no text output before retrieving BufInfo.wAttributes, then {color:reset} will set foreground and background color to black...
  ConOut := TTextRec(Output).Handle;
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(ConOut, BufInfo);
  ColorDict.Add('{color:reset}', BufInfo.wAttributes);
  while sString.Length > 0 do begin
    iFirstPos := sString.Length;
    for sKey in ColorDict.Keys do begin      
      if sString.Contains(sKey) then begin
        iPos := Pos(sKey, sString);
        if iPos < iFirstPos then begin
          iFirstPos := iPos;
          sFirstFind := sKey;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    if iFirstPos < sString.Length then begin
      Write(Copy(sString, 1, iFirstPos-1));
      sString := Copy(sString, iFirstPos+sFirstFind.Length);
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(TTextRec(Output).Handle, ColorDict[sFirstFind]);
    end else begin
      Write(sString);
      sString := '';
    end;
  end;
  ColorDict.Free;
end;
```